# Need help to add text with text field with Libre Office writer

Tags: libreoffice

Hi I am trying to create LO Basic Macro that add text with text field, and put some text to text fields like this:

```
If l>2 Then 
                'not first time, insert file after Doc5
                oText = Doc4.getText()
                oText2 = oText
                oText.insertString( oText.End, oText2, False ) 'THIS IS NOT WORKING
                oText.insertObject( oText.End, oText2, False ) 'THIS IS NOT WORKING
            Else
                Doc5 = StarDesktop.loadComponentFromURL(file1, "_hidden", 0, Dummy) 'open copied file
                Doc4 = Doc5
End If
oForm = Doc5.Drawpage.Forms.getByName("Form") 'Get Form'
oField = oForm.getByName("Textfield 1")   'Get access to field'
oField.Text = "some text..."
'Change name to text field, there is no need to use it any more, and new page in next round will have the textfield 1 -name
oField.Name = "Textfield" & Cstr(l)
l=l+1
```

Any Help? Regard Juha

Comment: While this is on topic here, since it is a question about a tool that runs on Linux and Unix systems, I fear you are unlikely to get an answer. I doubt we have many people who regularly use LO macros here (we might, I don't know, I just doubt it). You might want to think about deleting this and asking on [su] instead. I suspect they will have more experts on this sort of thing there.

Answer (score 0):

please check [here](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Macros/Writer/005) check [here](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Basic/Text_Field) and [here](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/GUI/Text_Field). I hope these links will help you.